# what type of internal memory do most digital cameras use? (not talking about SD cards or other removable storage)

Tags: flash, storage

I am looking into something for work and I need to know what type of flash-memory storage is most common in digital cameras so we can look into how to properly eradicate all of the data on the cameras's internal storage. I understand that there is more than likely not just one type of flash-memory in all cameras, but this is proving to be a difficult question to find the answer for, as all of my searches come back with information pertaining to the SD card for the camera. I am also trying to find out if a simple overwrite will be sufficient to ensure the data is permanently erased. these questions are aimed at digital cameras that were manufactured from 7 years ago to the present.

```
  -Thank you in advance!
```

Comment: It's most likely to be either simple embedded NAND/NOR flash or something like eMMC (which is much like an SD Card, but its a soldered IC not a card in a socket).

Comment: I would think if you really wanted to remove any information on the camera, it would involve destroying so much of the camera that you might as well just indiscriminately obliterate the entire camera. Thermite or blasting caps might be worth investigating. I take no responsibility for your injuries.

Comment: A sledgehammer and safety glasses should be quite sufficient. Or a trip through a kiln/furnace, in a suitable crucible so that you don't get camera all over the kiln/furnace.

Answer (score 1):

NAND/NOR flash is the best guess.  Not much info pertaining to design specs are available for digital cameras, so the best way to answer which make/model it houses is to visually inspect it by disassembling it down to the mainboard. 
Check for a chip marked with the logo of one of the flash manufacturers that existed in 2006 as a reference point  (Spansion, Intel, ST Microelectronics, Samsung, Toshiba, Sharp, Micron, Renesas, Macronix, Silicon Storage Technology)  Find the 8-20 character model number on the chip and Google it - you should be able to find design specs for the chip that confirm it's NAND/NOR.

Trim the leads to separate the chip from the mainboard and proceed to destroy the chip by way of introducing several physical cracks.  Use reasonable protection such as sticking it in between 2 layers of duct tape, wear gloves & goggles then smash it.

No publicly available software solution seems to exist as expected since everyone sets their own standard.

**Smashing the entire device and/or incinerating it - however valid - is in a grey area legally and ethically